# Validation error of type UnknownType: Unknown type CreateLeagueInput AWS Amplify GraphQL

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

I have the following schema

```
type League @model
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  faId: ID!
  logo: String
  seasons: [Season] @connection(keyName: "bySeason", fields: ["id"])
  division: [Division] @connection(keyName: "byDivision", fields: ["id"])
}
type Season @model @key(name: "bySeason", fields: ["leagueID"])
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  faId: ID!
  yearStart: AWSDate
  yearEnd: AWSDate
  leagueID: ID!
  league: League! @connection(fields: ["leagueID"])
  division: [Division] @connection(keyName: "byDivision", fields: ["id"])
}
type Division @model @key(name: "byDivision", fields: ["seasonID", "leagueID", "name"])
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  faId: ID!
  leagueID: ID!
  seasonID: ID!
  league: League! @connection(fields: ["leagueID"])
  season: Season! @connection(fields: ["seasonID"])
}
```

Which compiles perfectly well, I then do a mutation to create a league with:

[image] Which results in the below error

```
mutation MyMutation($name: String!, $faId: ID!) {
  createLeague(input: {name: $name, faId: $faId}) {
    id
  }
}

variables: 

{
  "name": "test 2",
  "faId": "9031785"
}
```

## Error Message

```
Error: Validation error of type UnknownType: Unknown type CreateLeagueInput
Validation error of type UnknownType: Unknown type ModelLeagueConditionInput
Validation error of type FieldUndefined: Field 'createLeague' in type 'Mutation' is undefined @ 'createLeague'
```

This same mutation works with graphiQL:
[image]

I have done a `codegen` and a `gql-compile`

## Edit... with docs definition.

[image]

Comment: just use 'shorter version' ? check if graphiql/docs shows mutation/input type

Comment: A very good point xadm... I did try this with the mutation: `export const CREATE_LEAGUE = gql
  mutation createLeague($name: String!, $faId: ID!) {
    createLeague(input: { name: $name, faId: $faId }) {
      id
      name
      faId
      logo
    }
  }
`

Comment: Which results in an error of `Error: Validation error of type FieldUndefined: Field 'createLeague' in type 'Mutation' is undefined @ 'createLeague'`

Comment: 'check if graphiql/docs shows mutation/input type'

Comment: It is listed under the `mutations` with a type of `League` which I set in the schema. I have added an image to the question

Comment: auth? compare raw network request details - graphiql vs. code

Comment: Ye, and thank you xadm :) It seems to me it must be authentication issue as I am using apollo-link and these packages are extremely "new". I have asked this question which might be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64072324/how-to-use-amazon-cognito-user-pools-with-apollo-client